# GUIMiner - Don't seem to recognize my GPU. Where to set it up?

Tags: gpu-mining, miner-configuration, guiminer

Please don't be rude, I'm not looking for making a living on bitcoin mining, I'm just experimenting with it a bit. At least I would like to, but I can not use properly the `GUIMiner`. I reckon that I should be getting a bit better rates, like twice as good as now.

I don't see any option to enable processing by the GPU, I can only see my CPU in the list.
My hardware: Intel Dual-Core E5200, 2GB DRR2 RAM, Radeon HD7730 2GB VGA.

I've already installed the AMD developer tools/kit, it made no difference.

It really looks like to me, that it only uses my CPU.

Screenshot:

[image: GUIMiner screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *is* recognizing your GPU, as "capeverde". ATI has code-names for their GPU revisions, such as Cape Verde, Winter Park, Tahiti, and so on, listed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_AMD_graphics_processing_units). Cape Verde matches your model on that list.